# Вычислить сумму членов ряда на языке Си

Tags: c, ряды

Для меня не понятно как с помощью языка Си, можно вычислить сумму ряда. Я не на столько хорош в этом языке, но хотел бы посмотреть как сделать это на этом примере:[image: сумма ряда]

Comment: Почитайте про цикл for

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%8b

Answer (score 1):

Все строго как написано:

```
double Sum(double x) {
    double z = 1 - x, y = -x;
    for(int n = 3; n <= 15; n + 2) {
        y *= -x*x/(n*(n-1));
        z += y;
        }
    return z;
    }
```